# Printing out values according to for-loop conditions

Tags: php, database, for-loop, laravel, laravel-4

I've created a *for loop*, but it does not print out the output according to the *for loop* conditions.

```
for( $c=0; $c < $total; $c++ ) 
{
    $latestID = AccessControlEntry::orderBy('AccessControlID', 'desc')->first();
    $numberID = explode("AC", $latestID->AccessControlID);
    $numberID[1] = $numberID[1] + 1;
    $newID = "AC";
    $newID = $newID.$numberID[1];    
}
```

I grabbed the last ID value (AccessControlID) from the database, and subsequently add 1 ($numberID[1] + 1) for every new entry in AccessControlID.

For eg: $total = 3. 
From my understanding of for-loops logic, shouldn't it print out 2 sets of $newID?

Can anyone tell me where/what did I went wrong?

Comment: Yes but you're overwring in every iteration the value of $newID. try to change this: `$newID = $newID.$numberID[1];` into this `$newID[] = $newID.$numberID[1];`at the end you'll obtain an array with all your new ids, you also have to delete `$newID = "AC";` otherwise you'll lose your array in the next step.

Comment: I've amended it like what you've described. However, it does not store the next value of the previous number. For eg: 6 and 7. 

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '6' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into 'accesscontrols' ('AccessControlID') values (6), (6))` 

Still couldn't understand why it doesn't store the right values. :\ 
@Cristian

Comment: in the code you provided above i didn't see any insertion in the DB.. can you post it? I thought you need to extract values from DB not insert them

Comment: `for( $c=0; $c < $total; $c++ )  
    {  
$latestID = AccessControlEntry::orderBy('AccessControlID', 'desc')->first();  
$numberID = explode("AC", $latestID->AccessControlID);  
$numberID[1] = $numberID[1] + 1;  
$newID[] = $numberID[1];  
$models[] = array('AccessControlID' => $newID[$c]);  
}  
DB::table('accesscontrols')->insert($models);`

Comment: before inserting values do a `print_r($newID)` in order to check them.

Comment: Here's the output.  
`Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 6 )`
Supposedly, this is how I want it to perform. 
1. Grab the latest value (eg. 5)
2. With the for-loop condition, add +1 for every next value. (eg. 6, 7, etc.)

Comment: So you should start your `$numberID` at `0`, however, you start at the second key in the array `[1]`. Try using your `$c` variable instead ... `$numberID[$c]`.

Comment: `$latestID = AccessControlEntry::orderBy('AccessControlID', 'desc')->first();`

`$numberID = explode("AC", $latestID->AccessControlID);` these two lines should be outside the loop.

Comment: It works!! Getting the output that I wanted. 
`Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 7 [2] => 8 )`
Thanks for the help!! And to others who helped as well! 
@Cristian

Comment: I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to bring outside the loop the lines of code which extract out from the DB the value.

```
$latestID = AccessControlEntry::orderBy('AccessControlID', 'desc')->first();
$numberID = explode("AC", $latestID->AccessControlID);

for( $c=0; $c < $total; $c++ ) {
    $numberID[1] = $numberID[1] + 1;
    $newID[] = $numberID[1];    
}

print_r($newID);
```